# jwt authentication node js work on local but not working on remote (heroku)

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I am trying to implement an authentication system for the express REST API.
I got this code for using jsonwebtoken from a tutorial.

when i run the app in local it works fine, i can log in and out but it doesn't when i deployed it on HERUKU, *app.get('/', (req, res)* returns *Invalid user to access it.*

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const utils = require('./utils');
const userData =require('./data.json')
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

// enable CORS
app.use(cors());
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


//middleware that checks if JWT token exists and verifies it if it does exist.
//In all future routes, this helps to know if the request is authenticated or not.
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  let token = req.headers['Authorization'];
  if (!token) return next(); //if no token, continue

  token = token.replace('Bearer ', '');
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: true,
        message: "Invalid user."
      });
    } else {
      req.user = user; //set the user to req so other routes can use it
      next();
    }
  });
});


// request handlers
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user) return res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid user to access it.' });
  res.send('Welcome to netperf Analytics back! - ' + req.user.name);
});

// validate the user credentials
app.post('/users/signin', function (req, res) {
  const user = req.body.username;
  const pwd = req.body.password;

  // return 400 status if username/password is not exist
  if (!user || !pwd) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: true,
      message: "Username or Password required."
    });
  }

  // return 401 status if the credential is not match.
  if (user !== userData.username || pwd !== userData.password) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      error: true,
      message: "Username or Password is Wrong."
    });
  }

  // generate token
  const token = utils.generateToken(userData);
  // get basic user details
  const userObj = utils.getCleanUser(userData);
  // return the token along with user details
  return res.json({ user: userObj, token });
});


// verify the token and return it if it's valid
app.get('/verifyToken', function (req, res) {
  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token;
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: true,
      message: "Token is required."
    });
  }
  // check token that was passed by decoding token using secret
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return res.status(401).json({
      error: true,
      message: "Invalid token."
    });

    // return 401 status if the userId does not match.
    if (user.userId !== userData.userId) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: true,
        message: "Invalid user."
      });
    }
    // get basic user details
    var userObj = utils.getCleanUser(userData);
    return res.json({ user: userObj, token });
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on: ' + port);
});
```

**utils.js**

```
// generate token using secret from process.env.JWT_SECRET

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// generate token and return it
function generateToken(user) {
  //1. Don't use password and other sensitive fields
  //2. Use the information that are useful in other parts
  if (!user) return null;

  var u = {
    userId: user.userId,
    name: user.name,
    username: user.username,
    isAdmin: user.isAdmin
  };

  return jwt.sign(u, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24 // expires in 24 hours
  });
}

// return basic user details
function getCleanUser(user) {
  if (!user) return null;

  return {
    userId: user.userId,
    name: user.name,
    username: user.username,
    isAdmin: user.isAdmin
  };
}

module.exports = {
  generateToken,
  getCleanUser
}
```

**error**

[image]

Comment: Put a log after this line in first middleware
  let token = req.headers['Authorization'];
i think req.headers is not containing the "Authorization" key. Reason for this may be you are testing it with postman in local env and set "Authorization" header explicitly.

Comment: hi, it shows nothing on console! with same message invalid user to access it even in localhost

Comment: Then you have to add "Authorization" header manually in postman.